# jQuery DataTables with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables

So i am trying to implement a pagination table with the datatables plugin, this is my first time using this plugin. I followed the documentation on the plugin and tried to get the values from the server through the use of Ajax, as per presented in the plugins documentation.

I seem to be getting the following error once i make the get request and i am unsure of why?

Error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

On client side i have the following code

```
viewReports = {
    init: function(){
        $('#paginatedData').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": '/viewreports'
        });

    }
};

$(document).ready(viewReports.init);
```

In my server side i have the following

```
router.get('/viewreports', function(res, req){

    async.parallel({
        viewReports: function(callback){
            restCall('/rest/bugbounty/latest/message/searchReport', 'POST', parameters, function(data){
                callback(null, data);
            }); 
        }
    }, function(err, result){
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.viewReports);
            res.render('viewreports');
        }
    });
});
```

Returned JSON:

> { reportList: [ { reportID: 'EIBBP-448', eBayUserID: ' ', reportStatus: 'New', summary: 'BugBounty Report created by Raj', lastUpdatedDate: '2015-06-15 01:05', createdDate: '2015-06-15 01:05', paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' } ], searchStatus: 'Success', eBayUserID: '', errorCode: '0', rowCount: '6', pageNumber: '1', paginationValue: '1', paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' }

It would be great to know if there is anyone who has worked with node.js server side processing for datatables

Comment: In server-side processing mode your server-side code should return data in the JSON format as described [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). Please post the JSON file that your server returns.

Comment: so there is no specific file where i am saving my json data to, but upon rendering the route '/viewreports' i am able to see the following value on the console { reportList: 
   [ { reportID: 'EIBBP-448',
       eBayUserID: ' ',
       reportStatus: 'New',
       summary: 'BugBounty Report created by Raj',
       lastUpdatedDate: '2015-06-15 01:05',
       createdDate: '2015-06-15 01:05',
       paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' } ],
  searchStatus: 'Success',
  eBayUserID: '',
  errorCode: '0',
  rowCount: '6',
  pageNumber: '1',
  paginationValue: '1',
  paypalLoginID: 'raaj@paypal.com' }

Comment: Do i need to stringify the above json value?

Comment: Your response is not correct for server-side processing mode, please read [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more details and data format. And yes, you need to return string in JSON format.

Comment: Please Check answer of pankaj kumar [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731153/jquery-datatable-with-nodejs-mysql/78165849#78165849](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731153/jquery-datatable-with-nodejs-mysql/78165849#78165849)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) and [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) - the following should work :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/viewreports",
        dataSrc: "reportList"
    },    
    columns: [ 
        { data : "reportID" },
        { data : "eBayUserID" },
        { data : "reportStatus" },
        { data : "summary" },
        { data : "lastUpdatedDate" },        
        { data : "createdDate" },        
        { data : "paypalLoginID" }
   ]     
});
```

on an empty table :

```html
<table id="example"></table>
```

- `dataSrc` to specify what the array holding row items is named (cause of "*Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*")
- `columns.data` to map item properties to columns

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't have to bother with the server side processing.
I used a simple way to trick `dataTables` initialization.

First, you will need to fetch the data you want to display in the table through your most preferred way, after you have confirm that data displays well, now head to where you initialize `dataTables` and make it so that it delays before initialization.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $('#yourtable').dataTable({
        // datatables customization options
    });
}, 100)
```

For example, in my case I gave it a delay of 100ms, and it works like a charm.